# Display problems on different screen sizes

Tags: html, css

There is a site that is displayed absolutely fine on my PC, but on a laptop or screen a scroll bar appears at the bottom, I tried to apply different styles to the wrapper, but if the site began to display normally, then problems began when the resolution was reduced.

Display on PC:
[image]

Display on laptop:
[image]

Display on laptop when changing resolution:
[image]

The site structure looks something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<section class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="main__content">
                    <h1>Content</h1>
                    <p>Content</p>
                    <p>Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</div>
```

Bounding box styles:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
    min-width: 1720px;
}
```

**Changes made:**

Added the following styles:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]
If you add a background, it looks like this:
[image]

But I need it to shrink adaptively when the resolution decreases, and so that the navigation in the site header does not run into each other.

Comment: Why do you have `min-width: 1720px;` for the wrapper element? This is your problem, if your screen is not that wide, it will scroll...you could easily just remove the  CSS there or set it to `width:100%` and it will always span the whole screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is making your wrapper have the set width of: `min-width: 1720px;` setting this min-width you are telling the element it has to be that large, which will look odd on mobile as those screens are not that large.

There are many fixes for this that are easy, but a quick example which simplifies your code slightly and gives the responsiveness you want is here:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  /* not actually needed */
}

.main__content{
  padding-left:40px;
  padding-right:40px;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main__content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

You noted in the comments that you have a "white" area that shows around the divs. To fix items like this and keep a background color consistent you need to style the area holding the page (i.e. `body`) to have the look you want.

For example, adding this to your body element will make the whole background blue:

```
body {
  background: blue;
  /* to make text legible */
  color: white; 
}
```

Comment: I added your styles to the project, the scrollbar disappeared of course, but when the resolution is reduced, a white area appears on the right.

Comment: @Salivan well, the example code you provided and the code I posted has no background color so it appears white everywhere by default. You'll need to post your full code with colors added to have someone look at that. This answer shows the responsiveness of `divs`

Comment: I added the changes to the question itself, so I think it will be easier.

Comment: @Salivan the whole answer I provided says, remove this: `.wrapper {
    min-width: 1720px;
}` this will remove the area that is "white" in your image

Answer (score 1):

The `wrapper` class has the property `min-width` set to `1720px` which indicates that your content can’t go lower that that width, which makes the horizontal scrollbar appear in lower resolution screens.

You probably want to choose a lower value for `min-width`

```
.wrapper {
  min-width: 340px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem has to do with your min-width attribute. If you change it to a max-width attribute with the same value, the scroll bar disappears.

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1720px;
}
```

You can still try a few things after that, like adding the min-width attribute as well, but with a lower value.

But that still works on PCs only and not on all screens. That's why you need to make your website responsive. The easiest way to do it is with media queries, where you define different CSS codes you want to run on 2 or 3 different screen sizes.

I'm not sure how you want your website to look in the end, therefore I suggest you watch a video or two on YouTube on Responsive Design. This should help you with your endeavors.

Comment: Yeah, but adding a `max-width: 1720px` here also limits the OP due to the fact that screen sizes are unknown in most instances. What happens if the page loads on a TV for an extreme example? --obviously a malformed page...also suggesting a poster to "look at YouTube" as a real response is a really bad answer and helps nobody that may stumble upon this question on the future...it is akin to telling someone to Google their problem

Comment: @ViaTech here's the thing, I tried to quick-fix his code for this specific scenario so he wouldn't leave empty-handed. I understand that max-width shouldn't be suggested most of the time, but as you said, the page loading on a TV is an "extreme example", so there's no reason to talk about that since 99.9% of us are not looking that much into it for our experimental/personal websites. Otherwise, my answer would be too long. The only thing I would change in my answer is, instead of suggesting max-width, I would suggest just using width or adding some padding.

Comment: @ViaTech Also, I suggested researching on YouTube, because the topic of Responsive Design is not easy to explain with examples in just a few sentences, and even though I had some relevant code for this example, it would take too much time to adjust it for this occasion and the answer would be too long to read.

Comment: Responsive design is super easy to explain, it is common web dev for the last decade or more less...a solution that doesn't limit the OP is a real solution. Sorry, I disagree with your post, but I'm only stating you should think about these things in future answers as yours in this instance is not vaiable for future readers